# Thread.Join method does not always return the same value when the thread has already terminated (.NET 5 / Core)

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-core

The `Thread.Join` method has three overloads: `Join()`, `Join(Int32)` and `Join(TimeSpan)`. For each of these three overloads, there is the following statement [in the Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.join?view=net-5.0):

> If the thread has already terminated when Join is called, the method returns immediately.

While this statement makes sense for the `Join()` overload, it doesn't specify which value is returned for the `Join(Int32)` and `Join(TimeSpan)` ones, so I tested the `Int32` overload in two different environments:

1. Windows 10: return **true**
2. Linux/Docker: return **false** (using [mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:5.0](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-runtime) on Docker Desktop)

Note that the Linux/Docker implementation is returning **true** (like the Windows one) if the thread is still running when `Join` is called and has terminated *after* the call. It only returns **false** if the thread has terminated *before* the call.

In my opinion `Join` should always return true whatever the platform, so what could explain this inconsistent behavior? Am I missing something or is it a .NET 5 bug?

**UPDATE**

As suggested by @txtechhelp, [here is a .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mruEO9) with the exact code I'm testing.

If I run this code on Windows 10 (or in .NET Fiddle) I get the following result:

```
Starting..
Sleeping 1200..expect T1 end before join
In T1
Leaving T1
Join(100)..expect success
Join(100) success!
Done..
```

Then if I run this code using [mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:5.0](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-runtime) on Docker Desktop (v. 3.1.0) then I get the following result:

```
Starting..
Sleeping 1200..expect T1 end before join
In T1
Leaving T1
Join(100)..expect success
Join(100) failed
Done..
```

**UPDATE 2**

Actually after further testing I realized that the test above is only failing if I call the `Join` when the Docker application is unloading (i.e. after receiving the `AssemblyLoadContext.Default.Unloading` event, which is the signal sent by Docker to inform that it's going to shutdown the application).

So [here is the exact test](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZxIJWw) which is even failing on .NET Fiddle:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.Default.Unloading += (arg) => { OnStopSignalReceived("application unloading"); };
    }

    public static void T1()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("In T1");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        System.Console.WriteLine("Leaving T1");
    }

    private static void OnStopSignalReceived(string stopSignalSource)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread t1 = new System.Threading.Thread(T1);
        System.Console.WriteLine("Starting..");
        t1.Start();
        System.Console.WriteLine("Sleeping 1200..expect T1 end before join");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1200);
        System.Console.WriteLine("Join(100)..expect success");
        if (t1.Join(100))
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Join(100) success!");
        }
        else
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Join(100) failed");
        }
        t1.Join();
        System.Console.WriteLine("Done..");
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it returns null?

Comment: @jdweng My question is about the int or TimeSpan overloads indeed, which return a non nullable boolean. I'm going to edit my question for clarification.

Comment: The doc that you linked states clearly: Returns "true if the thread terminated; false if the thread has not terminated after the amount of time specified by the timeout parameter has elapsed.". So I would suggest to file a Bug if an implementation returns false if the thread terminated.

Comment: @keuleJ Yes but maybe it returns true only if the thread has terminated **after** that the method was called? I'm not sure if this interpretation makes sense though... So the goal of my question is actually to figure out if this inconsistent behavior has already been observed and is to be expected, or if this is indeed a bug.

Comment: @Rem Would suggest asking this on the dotnet/runtime repo on GitHub, Microsoft will surely be able to tell you whether this is correct or a bug.

Comment: Bear in mind that a `false` return value is difficult to reason about because, by the time your code can "react" to such a value, the given thread may have exited.

Comment: Can you post any of the troublesome code? A quick test on multiple platforms (including Docker), yields the expected results. Here's the C# code I used to test what you're claiming: [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lYlq3i); as you can see, I specifically try and invoke the behavior you're saying in which a thread exits _and then_ `Yield(Int32)` is called, and in Linux you're getting a `false` value (meaning the thread did not exit yet and the time span specified passed). Relevant code would help to determine where the problem lies as it doesn't seem to be reproducible.

Comment: @txtechhelp As you suggested I just edited the question with a fiddle which is based on yours. I tested this code on Docker Desktop and I get `Join(100) failed`, which confirms my claim that Thread.Join has an inconsistent behavior according to the platform.

Comment: @txtechhelp Actually my fiddle is failing only if I call the test after the Docker unloading signal, please see my UPDATE 2 section that explains that.

Comment: @txtechhelp Ok now I have an exemple which is even failing in .NET Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZxIJWw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue *does* appear to be a bug in the underlying .NET 5 code for the [`AssemblyLoadContext` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.loader.assemblyloadcontext?view=net-5.0) or possibly some undefined behavior as not yet specified by the documentation; to wit, the documentation for the [`AssemblyLoadContext.Unloading` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.loader.assemblyloadcontext.unloading?view=net-5.0) merely states:

> Occurs when the AssemblyLoadContext is unloaded.

That is the only sentence and doesn't provide much context given the issue you're experiencing.

That being said, after some digging around, I wrote 2 versions of the code you supplied and found some interesting behavior dealing with the `AssemblyLoadContext.Unloading` and threads.

This code reproduces the bug you mention:

**buggy.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.Loader;

public class Program
{
        static Thread t1 = new Thread(ThreadFn);
        static Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    
        public static void Main()
        {
            AssemblyLoadContext.Default.Unloading += ContextUnloading;
            sw.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("{0}ms: leaving main", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }
    
        public static void ThreadFn()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}ms: in ThreadFn, sleeping 1s", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}ms: leaving ThreadFn", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }

        private static void ContextUnloading(AssemblyLoadContext context)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}ms: unloading '{1}', thread state '{2}'", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, context, t1.ThreadState);
            
            // possible bug/UB with t1.Start() in this function
            Console.WriteLine("{0}ms: starting thread", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            t1.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("{0}ms: calling Sleep(1200); expect thread in state '{1}' to end before join called", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, t1.ThreadState);
            Thread.Sleep(1200);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}ms: calling Join(100) on thread in state '{1}'; expect 'succeeded!'", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, t1.ThreadState);
            Console.WriteLine("Join(100) {0}", (t1.Join(100) ? "succeeded!" : "failed"));
            Console.WriteLine("{0}ms: done", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }
}
```

[Run it in dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RySwSv)

Running that code gives me the following results:

```
0ms: leaving main
12ms: unloading '"Default" System.Runtime.Loader.DefaultAssemblyLoadContext #0', thread state 'Unstarted'
13ms: starting thread
14ms: calling Sleep(1200); expect thread in state 'Running' to end before join called
14ms: in ThreadFn, sleeping 1s
1014ms: leaving ThreadFn
1214ms: calling Join(100) on thread in state 'Stopped'; expect 'succeeded!'
Join(100) failed
1214ms: done
```

You'll notice in this buggy version, the thread state at each point, and the time lapse, matches with the code presented. The bug happens when the [`Join(Int32)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.join?view=net-5.0#System_Threading_Thread_Join_System_Int32_) method is called; even though the documentation states the return value is a `Boolean` where the value is:

> `true` if the thread has terminated; `false` if the thread has not terminated after the amount of time specified by the `millisecondsTimeout` parameter has elapsed.

And given the thread was `Stopped`, which according to the [`ThreadState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadstate?view=net-5.0) documentation, means that the thread either responded to an `Abort` call (which is not called in the above code), or if

> A thread is terminated.

And reading the document [Understanding System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/dependency-loading/understanding-assemblyloadcontext), they make note to even

> **Be aware of thread races.** Loading can be triggered by multiple threads. The AssemblyLoadContext handles thread races by atomically adding assemblies to its cache. The race loser's instance is discarded. In your implementation logic, don't add extra logic that doesn't handle multiple threads properly.

Combine all of that, and we would assume calling `Join(Int32)` should give the expected result of `true` in the above code.

So, yes, it would appear to be a bug.

**However**

If you move the thread start in to the `Main` function, instead of in the unload event handler, the `AssemblyLoadContext.Unloading` on the `Default` context does not get called until the thread has finished, and calling `Join(Int32)` then, of course, returns the expected result.

It would make sense that the `Unloading` event would not be called until *after* the thread has completed, since it could be considered a "part" of the current assembly context, but it does not explain why the bug in the code above still happens.

So while the `Join(100)` call *does* succeed as expected in the code below, it would appear it's because the `AssemblyLoadContext.Unloading` does not get called after `Main` exits as one might expect, instead it is called after the thread has finished, which makes contextual sense but is not necessarily noted in any of the documentation.

The 'successful' code:

**syncbug.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.Loader;

public class Program
{
        static Thread t1 = new Thread(ThreadFn);
        static Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    
        public static void Main()
        {
            AssemblyLoadContext.Default.Unloading += ContextUnloading;
            sw.Start();

            // Get expected result starting thread, but Unloading isn't called until AFTER the thread
            // finishes, which is not the expected result according to the .NET documentation
            Console.WriteLine("{0}ms: starting thread", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            t1.Start();
            
            Console.WriteLine("{0}ms: leaving main", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }
    
        public static void ThreadFn()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}ms: in ThreadFn, sleeping 1s", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}ms: leaving ThreadFn", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }

        private static void ContextUnloading(AssemblyLoadContext context)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}ms: unloading '{1}', thread state '{2}'", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, context, t1.ThreadState);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}ms: calling Sleep(1200); expect thread in state '{1}' to end before join called", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, t1.ThreadState);
            Thread.Sleep(1200);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}ms: calling Join(100) on thread in state '{1}'; expect 'succeeded!'", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, t1.ThreadState);
            Console.WriteLine("Join(100) {0}", (t1.Join(100) ? "succeeded!" : "failed"));
            Console.WriteLine("{0}ms: done", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }
}
```

[Run it in dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SzPuLW)

Running that code gives me the following results:

```
0ms: starting thread
11ms: leaving main
12ms: in ThreadFn, sleeping 1s
1012ms: leaving ThreadFn
1013ms: unloading '"Default" System.Runtime.Loader.DefaultAssemblyLoadContext #0', thread state 'Stopped'
1014ms: calling Sleep(1200); expect thread in state 'Stopped' to end before join called
2214ms: calling Join(100) on thread in state 'Stopped'; expect 'succeeded!'
Join(100) succeeded!
2215ms: done
```

You'll note the `Unload` event is not called until *after* the thread has completed.

As of the writing of this answer, there are [82 open bugs for the `AssemblyLoadContext` class](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues?q=is%3Aissue+AssemblyLoadContext+is%3Aopen) and [346 closed](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues?q=is%3Aissue+AssemblyLoadContext+is%3Aclosed). So it's possible your issues is already noted in some way, but a cursory search didn't result anything that could relate to your issue.

Since this seems to be a legit bug, and since you have more insight to your code and what's happening, I'd recommend going to their [Issues](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues) page and filing a *New issue*.

Comment: Great answer! This seems to confirm this is indeed a .NET bug. So I just opened a ticket here: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/48807, let see what the .NET guys are saying...

Comment: @Rem just an FYI: I have a github account, so I can chime in over there too if you/they need any additional input on that issue. Nice write up btw!

Comment: FYI this bug has been triaged by Microsoft to be fixed in .NET 7 release.